# C++ Read Access Error while Printing List

Tags: c++, oop

I'm trying to create a basic linkedList then print next node of head node but i get a runtime error.

```
class LinkedListNode
{
public:
    LinkedListNode* next = NULL;
    string data;
    LinkedListNode(string data)
    {
        this->data = data;
    }
};

class LinkedList
{
public:
    int count = 0;
    LinkedListNode *head;
    void add(LinkedListNode obj)
    {
        LinkedListNode* browser = head;
        while (browser->next != NULL)
            browser = browser->next;
        browser->next = &obj;
        count++;
    }
};

int main()
{
    LinkedList list;
    list.head = new LinkedListNode("headnode");
    LinkedListNode a1("a1");
    LinkedListNode a2("a2");
    list.add(a1);
    list.add(a2);
    cout << list.head->next->data << "\n"; // <- HERE ERROR OCCURS 0xC0000005: 0xCCCCCCCC 
    cout << list.count;
}
```

Am i doing something wrong i cant figure out the reason of 0xC0000005: 0xCCCCCCCC

Comment: `browser->next = &obj;` takes and stores the address of a local variable that will be deleted once the function returns.

Comment: how can i pass parameter as a ref then

Comment: `void add(LinkedListNode& obj)` or `void add(LinkedListNode* obj)` . But you should also think about ownership and clarify who owns the elements in the list. Is a node the owner of the next node? That would be the usual way to do it. In your code the nodes are linked, but the owner is the client of the nodes.

Comment: Yes thats all defining parameter as "LinkedListNode& obj" solved the problem thank you

Comment: Ufuk, you expose too much about the inner workings of your `LinkedList` to the user. The user of the class should fypically not have to care about "Nodes" inside the list etc, only the values. I didn't write an answer regarding your current implementation but made some adjustments to show an alternative interface: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/pWfG6u). Perhaps you can pick some ideas from it.